# Removing specific days from highcharts datetime graph

Tags: datetime, highcharts

I'm using the xAxis datetime line type to graph hourly averages for the month of September and October. I have no data from the date range of Oct 14 - Oct 17. The resulting graph leaves a large gap where there is no data. Is there a way to remove those dates from the xAxis completely without having to create my own categories array?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. If you are using highcharts then using [`breaks`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks) is a good way:

```
xAxis: {
  breaks: [{
    from: 3,
    to: 7,
    breakSize: 1
  }]
```

}

This will remove anything between 3 and 7 on the xAxis, with a gap of 1 between them. To use this the broken-axis module needs to be imported:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/broken-axis.js"></script>
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/vsokqdL4/2/

---

If you are using highstock then having [`ordinal`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal) set to `true` (which is default) is a good way to do this.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/66rm2Lzh/

Comment: Thanks! That led me to the correct answer. Should be noted that broken-axis module is required.

Comment: Great! I added a line about needing the broken-axis module like you suggested.